# Acoustic power spectral density change due to diffraction

Tags: acoustics, diffraction, signal-processing

Say we have an acoustical point **source** emitting white noise - i.e., a power spectral density of $$S_x(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}$$ The source is embedded in the plane such that it radiates in half-space - i.e., a directivity factor $Q = 2$.

A **receiver** is located such that there's a step barrier between it and the source such that the total vertical displacement between source and receiver is $$h = h1 + h2$$
And the total horizontal displacement is
$$d = d1 + d2$$

[image]

**What is the power spectral density at the receiver?**

*edit 1:  I'm expecting the barrier to act a bit like a low-pass filter such that the resulting spectrum begins to roll off at a frequency of about $\frac{1}{h2}$, is that right?*

*edit 2: found [a helpful simulation by Kai Saksela](http://blog.kaistale.com/?p=954) based on a geometrical acoustics method from Svensson et al 1999.  Takes a while to load (10 minutes?), but appears to be the kind of approach that could find a solution.  It also makes me realize despite seeming like a pretty straightforward problem, it's probably quite complicated.*

*edit 3: there's actually [an entire Python library dedicated to the calculation of sound fields, `sfs-python`](https://github.com/sfstoolbox/sfs-python). From it I was able to calculate normalized sound fields with a barrier at a variety of frequencies and barrier distances. For example, a source at 1000 Hz, $h2 = 1.5 \ m$, and $d2 = 2.0 \ m$:*

[image]

*Though interesting, I'm interested in an analytical solution.*

Comment: Assuming a completely soundproof and non-reflecting barrier, the easiest way would probably be to just use Huygens' principle. Treat your source as a semicircle of sources on the circle whose center is at the real source and whose edge touches the corner of the barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the generalized calculation of diffraction-based attenuation at a specific frequency is given by the [**Kurze-Anderson formula**](http://acoustics.group.shef.ac.uk/asaproject.php),

$$\Delta L_B = 5 + 20 \ log \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi N}}{\text{tanh} \ \sqrt{2 \pi N}}$$

Where $N$ is calculated using different distances ($A$, $B$, and $d$) than the way the question was originally posed:
$N = \frac{2 \ f}{c} \cdot (A + B - d)$.

[image: updated diagram]

We can trivially convert using the Pythagorean theorem:

$$B = \sqrt{h1^2 + d1^2}$$
$$A = \sqrt{h2^2 + d2^2}$$
$$d = \sqrt{(h1 + h2)^2 + (d1 + d2)^2}$$

Then substitute, arriving at an expression in terms of our original distances.
$$N = \frac{2 \ f}{c} \cdot (\sqrt{h2^2 + d2^2} + \sqrt{h1^2 + d1^2} - \sqrt{(h1 + h2)^2 + (d1 + d2)^2})$$

---

Because barriers are much more effective at attenuating waves smaller than they are, we expect the barrier to work like a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency approximately the same size as $h2$.

Plotting the results for ($d1 = 10 \text{m}$,  $d2 = 10 \text{m}$,  $h1 = 1.5 \text{m}$,  $h2 = 0.5 \text{m}$) we find that this expectation is verified:

[image: clearer attenuation plot]